# Android NFC reader for FeliCa

Tags: android, nfc

I am new to NFC but have good experience in Android, looking for a sample application to read/cummunicate FeliCa enable device with Android NFC application.

Can you provide a link to a good tutorial for the same...........

Answer (score 0):

There is some code in the nfc-felica project. Note that you will only be able to read shared area data.

http://code.google.com/p/nfc-felica/

Comment: Note that the Android NFC stack will read automatically any NDEF data stored on a FeliCa-based NFC Forum Type 3 Tag. So for such tags you do not even have to communicate with the tag in your app to get at the data.

Comment: Are there any such tags in wide use? Never seen a FeliCa one.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. Regarding tags i'll let you know in next 1/2 days on this same discussion, right now i am just going through the commnuication specifications.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov FeliCa tags are in common use in Japan, Korea, parts of China and some other countries in that region. They are mainly used for public transport and payment systems. You usually won't see them in Europe or the US.

Comment: I meant FeliCa NDEF tags. FeliCa cards, sure, I have a bunch of those in my wallet :)

Comment: I have some [FeliCa Lite](http://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/products/RC-S965.html) stickers. About 4cm on each side. No idea how common they are.

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry to inform you that my client has scraped the project, because as per their understanding there is no future for NFC :(

Comment: Does android work with Felica card and Reader/Writer?